# How to compare 2 versions in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have 2 versions, lets say 1.0.2016.1000 and 1.0.2015.2000, out of which the first one is higher version.

How to do these comparision in vb6?

If both are same, it should return true without any looping. Else, it should do a minimum looping mechanism and return true if first version is greater and false if it is lesser.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below method to perform the comparison and it works as I expected.

StrComp(strFileName1, strFileName2, vbBinaryCompare)

Comment: This assumes the string representations of the two versions have same length and the dots are in the same places. Otherwise it will e.g. tell you that `2 > 19`.

Comment: In my case, always the string length and dots placement will be same. So this function will perfectly suits for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the version string on the decimal to do the compare:

```
Public Function CompareFileVersion(sFileName1 As String, sFileName2 As String) As Integer

    '// Return values:
    '// -1 = File Version 2 is greater than File Version 1
    '//  0 = Versions are the same
    '//  1 = File version 1 is greater than File Version 2
    Dim iResult As Integer

    Dim sFileVersion1 As String
    Dim sFileVersion2 As String
    Dim arrFileVersion1() As String
    Dim arrFileVersion2() As String
    Dim lVersion1 As Long
    Dim lVersion2 As Long
    Dim fs

    '// Let's initialize our result with 0
    iResult = 0

    '// Use FileSystemObject to get the file version
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFileVersion1 = fs.getfileversion(sFileName1)
    sFileVersion2 = fs.getfileversion(sFileName2)

    '// Split the two supplied file versions by the "." character
    arrFileVersion1() = Split(sFileVersion1, ".")
    arrFileVersion2() = Split(sFileVersion2, ".")

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFileVersion1())
        '// Convert the string to a number so we don't get false positive ("2">"19")
        lVersion1 = CLng(arrFileVersion1(i))
        lVersion2 = CLng(arrFileVersion2(i))
        If lVersion1 > lVersion2 Then
            iResult = 1
        ElseIf lVersion1 < lVersion2 Then
            iResult = -1
        End If

        'If we have found that the result is not > or <, no need to proceed
        If iResult <> 0 Then Exit For

    Next

    If UBound(arrFileVersion2) > UBound(arrFileVersion1) _
      And arrFileVersion2(UBound(arrFileVersion2)) <> 0 Then iResult = -1

    CompareFileVersion = iResult

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Call:

```
CheckVersion("1.0.2016.1000", "1.0.2015.2000")
```

Returns an integer:

`- 1` - second parameter/version is greater

`0` - both parameters/versions are the same

`1` - first parameter/version is greater

The function handles multiple length versions, like when comparing `2.1.1` with `2.2`, the latter being greater, and is smart enough to know that `2.1.0` is the same as `2.1`

```
Public Function CheckVersion(ByVal par1 As String, ByVal par2 As String) As Integer
    Dim arr1() As String
    Dim arr2() As String
    Dim looper As Integer
    Dim returnValue As Integer
    Dim val1 As Integer
    Dim val2 As Integer
    arr1 = Split(par1, ".")
    arr2 = Split(par2, ".")

    For looper = 0 To Max(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr2))
        val1 = 0
        val2 = 0
        If UBound(arr1) >= looper Then
            val1 = Val(arr1(looper))
        End If
        If UBound(arr2) >= looper Then
            val2 = Val(arr2(looper))
        End If

        If val1 > val2 Then
            returnValue = 1
            Exit For
        ElseIf val1 < val2 Then
            returnValue = -1
            Exit For
        Else
            ' same #, keep going
        End If
    Next
    CheckVersion = returnValue
End Function

Public Function Max(ByVal par1 As Integer, ByVal par2 As Integer) As Integer
    If par1 > par2 Then
        Max = par1
    Else
        Max = par2
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies. I have one more solution to achieve this.

```
Private Function CompareFileVersion(strFileName1 As String, strFileName2 As         String) As Boolean
```

' Return True if versions are equal.
    If StrComp(strFileName1, strFileName2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        CompareFileVersion = True
        Exit Function
    End If

```
Dim strAryFileVersion1() As String
Dim strAryFileVersion2() As String
strAryFileVersion1() = Split(strFileName1, ".")
strAryFileVersion2() = Split(strFileName2, ".")

' Return False if number of version segments differ.
If UBound(strAryFileVersion1) <> UBound(strAryFileVersion2) Then
    CompareFileVersion = False
    Exit Function
End If

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(strAryFileVersion1())
    '' Return True if current version segment greater than expected version segment.
    If CLng(strAryFileVersion2(i)) > CLng(strAryFileVersion1(i)) Then
        CompareFileVersion = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    ' Return False if current version segment less than expected version segment.
    If CLng(strAryFileVersion2(i)) < CLng(strAryFileVersion1(i)) Then
        CompareFileVersion = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    ' Current/Expected version segments are the same, continue to the next segment.
Next

CompareFileVersion = True
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**Call:**

```
CompareVersions("1.0.2016.1000", "1.0.2015.2000")
```

*Works perfectly for me with any numbers*

**Declarations:**

```
Function SameLength(ByVal Ver1 As String, ByVal Ver2 As String) As String
    Dim diff As Integer, num2 As Integer
    diff = UBound(Split(Ver2, ".")) - UBound(Split(Ver1, "."))
    SameLength = Ver1 & String((diff + Abs(diff)) / 2, ".")
End Function

Function CompareVersions(Ver1 As String, Ver2 As String) As Boolean
    Ver1 = SameLength(Ver1, vel2)
    Ver2 = SameLength(Ver2, Ver1)
    If Ver1 = Ver2 Then CompareVersions = True: Exit Function
    Dim xSplit1() As String, xSplit2() As String
    xSplit1 = Split(Ver1, ".")
    xSplit2 = Split(Ver2, ".")
    For x = 0 To UBound(xSplit1)
        If Val(xSplit1(x)) > Val(xSplit2(x)) Then
            CompareVersions = True: Exit Function
        ElseIf Val(xSplit1(x)) < Val(xSplit2(x)) Then
            CompareVersions = False: Exit Function
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

- Returns `True` if the first version is equal to or greater than the second version.
- Returns `False` if the first version is less than the second version.

**Tests:**

```
CompareVersions("1.0.2016.1000", "1.0.2015.2000")   'True
CompareVersions("1.0.2015.2000", "1.0.2015.2000")   'True
CompareVersions("1.2.3.4.5", "1.2.3.4.5.1")         'False
CompareVersions("1.2.3.4.5.1", "1.2.3.4.5")         'True
CompareVersions("9.9.9", "8.8.8.8.8.8")             'True
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This will compare even if the number of version segments differ, which I think is logically the correct approach